# Can I use "small" and "little" together to express irony and contempt?

Tags: word-usage, connotation, irony

I know the difference between *small* and *little*. I see that they are not so commonly used together, in any case less commonly than *tiny little*, as this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tiny%20little%2C%20small%20little&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows.

Here is one example that does not express irony, it is just emphatic:

> Imagine *a **small little** speck of matter*, so small we cannot see it through the most powerful light microscope in the world. (*[God and Randomness](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WklBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&dq=%22small%20little%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgh6TMtZuAAxWLTkEAHcumAfQ4ChDoAXoECAYQAg)*, Thomas R. McFaul, ‎Al Brunsting, 2017).

In the following example it bears an affectionate connotation:

> There sat a young and ***small little*** girl. I passed her so friendly with my dog and rucksack and said openly "Hello" to her, when she answered in the same loud and friendly tone back her "Hello" that was so warm and welcoming. (*[Little Wolf III: About my Love](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=48qxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA202&dq=%22small%20little%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPnrmFuJuAAxUT_rsIHUvSDNE4HhDoAXoECAcQAg)*, Heike Thieme, 2019)

If, however, I use it in combination with *life*, does this sentence come across as ironic and contemptuous? It is addressed by a boss to an employee who almost got fired. I don't want the sentence to sound affectionate, it would be the contrary of what I am trying to convey.

> If you love ***your small little life***, you'd better serve the company.

Comment: A 'little girl' is a very young girl. A 'small little girl' is a very young girl who isn't as big as other little girls and as you say there is no put-down. But about someone's *life* either of 'small' or 'little' are put-downs: more so when used together. OTOH 'short life' is a more of a factual description than pejorative.

Comment: A more familiar contemptuous usage of "small little" is in phrases like "small little brain" or "small little minds".